# Compare: Azure Functions vs Azure Batch

Tags: azure

Can we use Azure Functions along with Azure Batch? Please Advise.

I am working on a POC to decide which one to use for our background processes.

Comment: Hi, I find it very difficult to give any advice since we have no idea what your use case is. What kind of background process are we talking about? Try to see it from our perspective and maybe you can see we have too little information to help you as it is right now. So please add more details to the question.

Comment: To help decide which Azure compute service to use, try [Choose an Azure compute service](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/architecture/guide/technology-choices/compute-decision-tree)

Answer (score 2):

I too was in similar dilemma till I tried both of them for my use case.

The major difference between the two is that Azure Function has a hard timeout limit of I guess 10 minutes which you can not exceed. What I mean is that if your script/execution runs beyond 10 minutes then Azure function will kill it automatically.

Whereas Azure batch is essentially a configuration of pools or VMs in which you can run long running jobs where you are not bothered about the time of its execution. Essentially they are old VMs (low costs too). Difference between batch and Azure VMs is that Azure VMs have high speed VMs but in batch you can configure the periodic jobs where in Azure VMs you need to code in such a way that it executed like a periodic job

And yes it is possible to use Functions with Azure batch. You can configure your script as HTTP trigger in Function which you can call (get/post) through Azure Batch VMs.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Configuration is another big deal too. VMs can be configured better based on your needs (high CPU / high memory etc...), but for the functions it's all tier based. Which means you can't really configure your function's hardware.

Comment: The comparison is more difficult now that Azure Functions has a Premium plan that allows for unbounded run time (Ignoring whether or not that is a good practice).
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-premium-plan

Comment: another con for Azure Batch (it seems) to not have a way to deploy it thru azure pipelines, so it would have to be a manual configuration (though it does have a Terraform module)

Answer (score 0):

May be we should expand this topic to Azure services for Batch processing in general. I did come across an [article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/architecture/best-practices/background-jobs) from Microsoft that goes through these options in general (which includes Web Jobs, and Kubernetes options).

But, frankly, even after reading the article; the confusion remains. For example, Azure Batches can be scheduled; but not sure if they can be triggered based on other Azure services like how Azure web jobs handles it. I get a feeling that Azure Batch is pitched where you need high + parallel computing at low costs. Because, none of the other options directly allow you to low-priority and low-cost compute instances. Correct me please!

```
#AzureBatch #AzureWebJobs #AzureAKS #AzureFunctions
```

Answer (score 0):

Azure Batch - if you task and running long time continually without any interruption then you should go with Azure Batch.
use Azure Batch to run large-scale parallel and high-performance computing (HPC) batch jobs efficiently in Azure.

Azure function - for small task max limit 15 min Cost is also involved. If you want to execute based on trigger.